# Why doesn't a proc care about the number of arguments?

Tags: ruby, proc

```
def method1(&proc)
  proc.call(1,2,3)
end

method1{ |x,y,z,a| puts a}
```

Doesn't throw any error and outputs `nil`.

Why doesn't it check for the arguments? What's the logic behind it?

Comment: The [Ruby documentation for `proc`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Proc.html) says "A Proc object generated by proc ignores extra arguments...It provides nil for missing arguments.". That is what is happening in your case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Proc`'s do no care about validating the right number of arguments but lambda's do...

```
def method1(&proc)
  proc.call(1,2,3)
end

method1 { |x,y,z,a| puts a}
method1 lambda { |x,y,z,a| puts a }
```

Results in:

```
lambda.rb:1:in `method1': wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 0) (ArgumentError)
    from lambda.rb:6:in `<main>'
```

From the [ruby docs](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.2/Proc.html):

> For procs created using lambda or ->() an error is generated if the wrong number of parameters are passed to a Proc with multiple parameters. For procs created using Proc.new or Kernel.proc, extra parameters are silently discarded.

Comment: @InQusitive : I haven't used this feature myself, but it well might be of some use for meta-programming patterns.